# How to add breadcrumbs in my account pages

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, xml, frontend, breadcrumbs

I want to add **Breadcrumbs** in my account page & it should be displayed on every tab selection below the Navigation menu bar.

But it is not showing anything on my page it is looking like this

[image]

But when I am watching for the hints it is showing me like this 
[image]

Which means **breadcrumb** is there but then why it is not showing there?
I want it to be shown like this

[image]

How could I get this to be done?

Comment: remove your above xml and check where display your breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Breadcrumbs** need to be **added for each action**. For example for **`customer_account_create.xml`**

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">account</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account</item>
            <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/customer/account</item>
        </argument>
    </action> 
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">account.create</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Customer</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Customer</item>
            <item name="last" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

> More detail You can look at the github in module [Breadcrumbs](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.Breadcrumbs)

Comment: Do I need to put this xml for every tabs by making there own xml file or how could I get this because as I will select different tabs in customer account It should get changed

Comment: Yes, for every tabs and actions (about 25) needed independent xml. Filenames XML You can find in the directory view\frontend\layout of modules customer, sales, review, wishlist, downloadable, etc.

Comment: the breadcrumbs are ready but when I click on the link like here the account will bi the link so it should needed to go on the account page means on the dashboard of the customer but it showing the wrong link to me

Comment: what should be the right link?

Comment: the right link should be `localhost/magento_test/customer/account` as of **magento_test** is my root directory of magento but it is not taking it into the link consideration

Comment: This is because Your baseurl contains a subfolder. It is Relative URLs. On the real domain everything will be ok.
Try adding a tag base to your html template in head section and removing the first slash from xml (item name="link" xsi:type="string">customer/account).
tag base link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521011/why-base-tag-does-not-work-for-relative-paths

Answer (score 2):

I am putting this answer because It is working properly with this code & the links are also clickable & goes to the right place when we click.

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">home</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}</item>
              </argument>
            </action> 
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">account</argument>
                   <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account</item>
                      <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account</item>
                      <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}/customer/account</item>
                  </argument>
            </action> 
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">orders</argument>
                  <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders</item>
                    <item name="last" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
```

> Note: you need to add this code as per your requirement in each &
>   every page's layout.xml for getting breadcrumbs there into that page
>   the above example is for **`sales_order_history.xml`(My Orders)**

Comment: When I add the breadcrums on the customer_account.xml he removes menu items on the left? For example newsletter subscriptions. Weird

Comment: may be you have called your breadcrumb block at wrong position so please find it & move it to the appropriate place & then try with it

Answer (score 0):

**To put breadcrumb on My Account pages ==**

> My Account Dashboard ==
>
> ```
> file path: /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/ customer_account_index.xml
> ```
>
> My Orders ==
>
> ```
> file path: /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/ sales_order_history.xml
> ```
>
> My Wish List ==
>
> ```
> /vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/ wishlist_index_index.xml
> ```
>
> My Address Book ==
>
> ```
> /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/ customer_address_index.xml
> ```
>
> My Account Information ==
>
> ```
> /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/ customer_account_edit.xml
> ```
>
> Newsletter Subscription ===
>
> ```
> /magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/layout/ newsletter_manage_index.xml
> ```

I tried to put on these pages. It is working well and show breadcrumb.

Comment: Hi @Nang breadcrumbs are available on all pages (except checkout), so you can add it to any of the XML files referring the block name `<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">` I have added my answer because I was using different directory on my server so in my case it worked with `Base URL`.

Comment: Thanks. @AbhishekTripathi